# How can we delete Elastic Search mapping if index is already deleted

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I deleted an Elastic Search index but seems its mapping is still present in ES.
When I am trying to create index with changing mapping data type its still taking old one, below is the error:
Failed: Failed to parse mapping: dynamic template [priority_sort] has invalid content [{"match":"priority_*","path_match":"doc.*","mapping":{"fielddata":true,"type":"integer"}}], attempted to validate it with the following match_mapping_type: [object, string, long, double, boolean, date, binary]

How can we delete old mapping if index is not present?

I tried to create index but getting error

Comment: It might be that you have an index template being triggered, can you verify if the index templates you get when retrieving `GET _cat/templates?v` have a matching index pattern?

Comment: yes, getting the same pattern from this query. Do I need to delete this, if yes how can I delete?
this was the output:
discovery                      [discovery*]                 0          2       []

but when I tried to delete it using command:
curl -X DELETE -k -u user:password "https://<host>:9201/_template/discovery"

getting an error as "{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_template_missing_exception","reason":"index_template [discovery] missing"}],"type":"index_template_missing_exception","reason":"index_template [discovery] missing"},"status":404}"

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an index templates whose index pattern matches the index you're creating.

If you hit the following endpoint, you should see if that's the case:

```
GET _cat/templates?v
```

if you can find the template you're looking for, you can delete it using either of the two following endpoints depending on whether you have a legacy template or new template:

```
DELETE _template/template_name (legacy template)
DELETE _index_template/template_name (new template)
```

Comment: thanks Val, indexed were created after deleting index template

Comment: Awesome, glad to know it worked out!

Comment: Feel free to accept if it helped ;-)